# Stage 1 bootloader to print a string

Tags: string, assembly, operating-system, bootloader

I want someone yo explain something to me please: so Im trying to follow some book to write my first super simple OS.
I wrote a code that prints a "hello world" string using int 0x10.

My code is:

```
[Org 0x7c00]

Mov bx,hello_msg

Mov ah,0x0e


Loop: mov al,[bx]

      cmp al,0

      Je exit

      int 0x10

      Inc bx

      Jmp loop

exit:

  Jmp$

hello_msg db 'Hello world',0


times 510-($ - $$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

So the thing is I copied the content of the resulted binary file after  using NASM,to the boot sector of a flash memory
And booted from the flash memory the only thing that happened is that the cursor went to the bottom of the screen and printed a single weird character. If I change my code to print the hello msg character by character by loading a character to the al (the low byte of ax register) and 0x0e to ah and int 0x10,it works perfectly I tried different codes to print the string but nothing worked except for the character by character printing.
Does anyone have any clue of what could be causing this behavior? 
Im really confused,and I would really like to understand what is going on.
Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to set up `ds`. Since you have `org 0x7c00` use `xor ax, ax; mov ds, ax` at the start.

Comment: Thanks a million @Jester ! it worked :)